# Kotlin compiler mixing up reified type parameters

Tags: generics, kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I think I may have encountered a compiler bug regarding reified type parameters. It’s probably easiest to explain with a code example:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println("Same:");

    proxySame<Int>();
    directSame<String, Int>();

    println("\nDifferent:");

    proxyDiff<Int>();
    directDiff<String, Int>();
}


inline fun <reified P> proxySame() = directSame<String, P>();
inline fun <reified P, reified Z> directSame(
    func: () -> Unit = {
        println(Z::class.java.simpleName)
    }
) = func();


inline fun <reified P> proxyDiff() = directDiff<String, P>();
inline fun <reified Q, reified Z> directDiff(
    func: () -> Unit = {
        println(Z::class.java.simpleName)
    }
) = func();
```

This example is obviously not a real-world scenario, but it’s the simplest program I could find that still manifests the unexpected behavior.

In this code there are 2 types of functions: `directX` and `proxyX`, where `X` is either `Same` of `Diff`. The only difference between the `Same` and `Diff` functions is **the name of the first type parameter of the `directX` function**. For `Same` it’s the same as the `proxyX` function, for `Diff` it’s different.

One would expect the output to be the same, regardless of whether `directX` was called through the proxy function or not. Unfortunately, this is apparently not always the case:

```
Same:
String         (proxy, wrong)
Integer        (direct, correct)

Different:
Integer        (proxy, correct)
Integer        (direct, correct)
```

As you can see the output is different when calling through the proxy function, **but only if the reified type parameters have the same name**.
The value of P of the proxy function has somehow ended up in the Z of the direct function. However, **this only happens inside the lambda function**, printing the class name in the regular function body leads to the expected result.

I’m at a complete loss here. I can’t find any other explanation for this, other than it being a compiler bug. Have I truly run into some obscure bug, or have I somehow missed something here?

**Edit: I have opened a bug report for this [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-36237).**

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me, I'd suggest opening it as a bug on their bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newissue?project=kt&draftId=25-2646793

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the decompiled bytecode you can see that `proxyDiff()` seems to regard the generic parameter `P` and `proxySame()` does not.

```
public final void proxyDiff() {
   // ...
   Intrinsics.reifiedOperationMarker(4, "P");
   String var5 = Object.class.getSimpleName();
   // ...
}

public final void proxySame() {
   // ...
   String var5 = String.class.getSimpleName();
   // ...
}
```

My guess is that it is optimized away during inlining.

The compiler sees that `P` is not used in `directSame()` and thus infers that it is also not used in `proxySame()`. So this:

```
inline fun <reified P> proxySame() = directSame<String, P>();
inline fun <reified P, reified Z> directSame(
        func: () -> Unit = {
            println(Z::class.java.simpleName)
        }
) = func();
```

becomes this under the hood:

```
inline fun proxySame() = directSame<String>();
inline fun <reified Z> directSame(
        func: () -> Unit = {
            println(Z::class.java.simpleName)
        }
) = func();
```

So, yes I would definitely say it is a bug.